# Javascript keypress

Tags: javascript, html

Try to do something hide alert window by pressing spacebar or any key in keyboard.

existing only able to do using click listener.

```
$('.alertWindow1').click(function (event) {
    s.hide();
});
```

Trying this code but not able function

```
$('.alertWindow1').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
         s.hide();
    }
});
```

This is full existing code, try to add hide the alert window using keypress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.extend({
        alertWindow: function (e, n) {
            var e = e, r; n === undefined ? r = "#00a8b7" : r = n;
            if ($("body").find(".alertWindow1").length === 0) {
                var i = '<div class="alertWindow1" style="width: 100%;height: 100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);position: fixed; left:0px; top: 0px; z-index: 9999;"><div id="successImg" style="margin-top:200px;margin-left:20px;text-             align:center;" >' + "</div>" + "</div>";
                $("body").append(i);
                var s = $(".alertWindow1");
                var ddbarcode = $('#hidbarcode').val();
                if (ddbarcode != "") {
                    displayCard(ddbarcode);
                    
                }
                $('.alertWindow1').click(function (event) {
                    s.hide();
                });
            }
            else {
                $(".alertWindowContent").text(e), $(".alertWindow1").show(), setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".alertWindow1").hide();
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    })

</script>
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using `keyCode` as it's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: What element is `.alertWindow1`?

Comment: Try event.key and a window listener... instead of a class.

Comment: @blanknamefornow `which` is non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which

Comment: Ooops, yeah it is; corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about where the event is firing, and where it will bubble to.

Key events start wherever the **focus** is.

The `div` you are adding to the document isn’t focusable. It has no descendants that are focusable. Even if it did, you haven’t done anything to move the focus from where it is now to such an element.

So the key event will start where the focus is now and bubble up until it hits the `document` object without even passing through that `div`. This means it never passes anywhere that you listen for it.

You can listen on the `document` object instead.